# Informix JDBC ISO-8859-2 encoding problem

Tags: java, jdbc, encoding, informix, iso-8859-2

I have a problem with string encoding in my Java application. My Informix database has ISO-8859-2 encoding. I have set `DB_LOCALE` in a connection string. My connection URL looks like:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://test/test:informixServer=test;portNumber=1542;databaseName=test;serverName=test_informix;ifxIFXHOST=test;DB_LOCALE=pl_PL.8859-2;DBDATE=Y4MD-;IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=10;
```

After selecting data from database, Polish special characters are not recognised by Java String. `charAt()` method returns `65533` code.

I tried to look at hex code of that string:

```
String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, input.getBytes("ISO-8859-2"))));
```

And the result is valid. Any ideas where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out the solution. The problem was in `LANG` system variable. It was empty on my machine. After changing it to `en_US.ISO-8859-1` strings are handled properly.